# Is it wrong to say "Music Concert"?

Tags: meaning, redundancy

Concerts, by definition, feature music. Isn't specifying a concert to be a *music* concert needlessly redundant?

Comment: I think *needlessly redundant* is a redundancy. Why not just say *redundant* here?

Comment: I agree with Robusto

Comment: Manoochehr's comment agreeing with Robusto is also redundant as well.

Comment: What’s wrong with being redundant? The chance that more people might understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Concert* means "a performance of music" given by musicians or singers. So it's not true to use *music concert*.

But it's fine to say "Rock Music Concert", because you're talking about the type of music, not the concert.

Comment: Although it's also fine to say Rock Concert. I've never heard Metal Music Concert, but Metal Concert sounds fine. I suppose that's because there's no phrase Metal Music.

Comment: @Matt: That's right. Because you're specifying the type of concert.

Answer (score 8):

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org) has 60 cites for *music concert*, so it's not "wrong" per se. It can be a [pleonasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm), but not necessarily so. Many cites in the Corpus are of the form "baroque music concert", "country music concert", etc. Saying "baroque concert" or "country concert" would not be quite the same, as it could introduce ambiguity.

Comment: As _concert_ has two different meaning, I agree that _music concert_ is not a pleonasm.

Comment: _concert (n.)_ 
_1660s, "agreement, accord, harmony," from Fr. concert (16c.), from It. concerto "concert, harmony," from concertare "bring into agreement," in L. "to contend, contest, dispute," from com- "with" (see com-) + certare "to contend, strive," frequentative of certus, variant pp. of cernere "separate, decide" (see crisis)._ See [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=concert&searchmode=none)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say not as many different things can be 'in concert' or acting together. An astrologist may speak of 'a concert of planets' or a physicist 'a concert of forces.' 'Music concert' specifies a concert of sound and instruments. Although nowadays it does seem that the primary definition of 'concert' is 'music concert.' Though what would perhaps be most correct is 'a concert of music'?