# Is "best regards" a pleonasm?

Tags: phrases, pleonasms

If the meaning of *regards* is *best wishes*, would not *best regards* (used to express friendliness in greetings, especially at the end of letters) a pleonasm, in the context of letters?

> Best regards,
>   kiamlaluno

> Best best wishes,
>   kiamlaluno

Comment: The meaning of *regards* is not *best wishes*.

Comment: That's what the NOAD reports.

Comment: All five answers below disagree, and I think you should give them (and other dictionaries) more consideration in light of the answers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - you're referring to the context of letter writing - I think you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: This question has been significantly changed by the edit.

Comment: The meaning of the question is the one I always meant for it. The fact I always found _best regards_ at the end of letters/emails made me think that was the only context where I could find _best regards_. I then made explicit the context, and that is why the question changed.

Comment: The fact that "regards" might be *equivalent* to "best wishes" just means that both can be used in the same circumstances, with roughly the same intent (a polite close to a letter) conveyed. There is no suggestion that "regards" specifically *means* "best wishes". To compare: saying "bye" is largely the same as saying "goodbye". But that doesn't mean that "goodbye" is the same as "goodgoodbye", "goodgoodgoodbye" etc :-)

Comment: @psmears: wonderful example!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think there are two main points here:

- ***Regards*** does not only, nor originally, mean *best wishes*.  In some particular contexts — most often, as closing salutations in letters or emails — they’re indeed effectively synonymous.  But *regards* has other meanings as well.  Originally, *regards* carried no specific connotations of being *good*; it just so happened that one of its most frequent usages was for sending people kind wishes, and so in that context, it picked up those connotations.
- Even if that were its only meaning, **synonyms are not exact**, and **meaning is not substitutive** — synonyms are very, very rarely so exactly synonymous that you can always substitute them for each other without changing meanings.

  For instance, as synonyms go, *puppy* and *young dog* are pretty close — close enough that one might reasonably say “*puppy* is defined as *young dog*”.  (Indeed, checking a couple of dictionaries, it is.)  But *a young puppy* is not redundant: we know it means (in most contexts) a dog that is young even for a puppy.  Nor is *an old puppy* an oxymoron.  In isolation, *puppy* means almost exactly *young dog*; but it’s picked up different connotations, so in many contexts, replacing *puppy* with *young dog* can change the meaning of a phrase significantly.  This is why pleonasm is often rather effective: ‘technical’ redundancy can be an illusion.

  Substituting synonyms to check whether something makes sense is often helpful nonetheless, as a very rough rule of thumb.  But when it doesn’t work, one shouldn’t be too surprised.

Comment: It's just young dog love ...

Answer (score 5):

**a)**

The answer to the question is No.You might **regard someone with a complete lack of respect**! So using regards alone doesn't clearly show how you feel about someone you're corresponding with. Of course in correspondence using "regards" alone doesn't have a negative connotation and is used to show good wishes.

**b)**

Sometimes **pleonastic usage** is welcomed. The usages are:

> 1. Idiomatic expressions
> 2. Professional and scholarly use
> 3. Stylistic preference
> 4. Literary uses

For getting more information visit [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm#Literary_uses)

So for emphasizing or making the purpose clear we might use redundancies. For example:

> "This was the **most unkindest** cut of all." —William Shakespeare, Julius Caesar.

Comment: I disagree with a). While regards in general aren't necessarily always positive, do you have references for someone *signing off a letter* (which is the context of this question) with disrespectful regards?

Answer (score 4):

No, because I might regard you with disdain, or my worst regards.

Comment: PS: I had to look up pleonasm, thanks for the new word! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm

Comment: _Worst regards_ sounds a contradiction, if _regards means _best wishes_. What would _worst best wishes_ be?

Comment: Despite common usage, the unadorned word "regards" does not mean "best wishes". It's only when you prepend "best" it takes on a similar meaning.

Comment: I read the word _pleonasm_ [in this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/is-it-wrong-to-say-music-concert/11030).

Comment: Well in that case I thank @RegDwight for it, and I thank you for using it today.

Comment: The meaning of _regards_ (not _regard_) reported fron the NOAD is just one: _best wishes (used to express friendliness in greetings, especially at the end of letters)_. As example, the dictionary reports _Warm regards, Helen_ and _give her my regards_; in both the cases, _regards_ is not preceded from _best_, but still the meaning is _best wishes_.

Comment: I don't have a NOAD to hand, but dictionary.com lists a number of meanings and the first is the one I expected; to look upon or think of with a particular feeling (no implied feeling)

Comment: I see regards as just a greeting. "My Salutations" - "Give my BEST salutations to..." or "Give my salutations to..."

Comment: @Ed Guiness, dictionary.com's specific reference for a valediction is *regards, sentiments of esteem or affection: Give them my regards. *, and I think we can all agree that no-one signs a letter with any regards other than positive ones; I'd certainly be interested to see references of when this isn't so.

Answer (score 1):

*Regards* doesn't carry with it a very open and public sense of *best* that you're talking about. Most people probably just understand it as something like "good wishes" or some other non-superlative and bland but positive way to express friendship. So *Best regards* at the end of a letter, if it got noticed at all, would simply be read as equivalent to *Best wishes*.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give someone kind regards, or warm regards, so specifying best regards is not redundant.  As PLL points out, "regards" by itself does not equate to "best wishes"; I think of it in this usage as "the worth or estimation in which something or someone is held" ([Merriam-Webster](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regard) definition 4a).  In effect, you're closing with a little note letting the person know that you have a good opinion of them.

Answer (score 0):

*Regards* is used to hide the emotional content of your salutation. I once had a manager who told me there is no room for emotion in business, which I do not find to be true.

However, when needing to maintain a professional air surrounding emails and letters, *regards* is a snappy quick way of saying (more often then not) 'best wishes'; which therefore makes 'best regards' a redundancy.

Comment: The OP's question is whether "best regards" is a pleonasm, not really a request for help using it.

Comment: Yes, this in no way answers or addresses the question.

Comment: @Jon "which therefore makes 'best regards' a redundancy." It answers the question.

Comment: @KittenCanoodle Ah. I see now. It's not a redundancy though, since "regards" in this sense is a elided form of "best regards", "kind regards" and similar, and without those forms existing previously we wouldn't understand the bare "regards". But that's it being wrong, rather than irrelevant as my misreading led me to interpret it as.

Comment: @Jon *nods* I left my comment because you are not the only one who misread it, if you catch my meaning.